# How to add multiple category in custom post type textonomy . is it possible?

Tags: wordpress

i can't add multiple category in custom post type

please send me the code that can I use to add many category in taxonomy
help me please.

I try this but I was not success   'taxonomies'=> array('topics', 'category' ),

Answer (score 1):

When you register a custom post type you can add taxonomies as arguments in register_post_type function

```
add_action('init', 'register_CPT');
function register_CPT() {
  register_post_type('CPT',array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'menu_position' => 5,
    'taxonomies' => array( 'topics', 'category'),
    'can_export' => true
  ));
}
```

But if both taxonomy and custom post type are existed, you can add each taxonomy to CPT by register_taxonomy_for_object_type function

```
add_action( 'init', 'add_taxonomy_to_CPT' );
function add_taxonomy_to_CPT() {
  register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'topics', 'CPT' );
  register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'category', 'CPT' );
}
```